How to export SFINAE-constrained ctor defined in cpp file for explicitly instantiated template class?
Here's my attempt:

The header defining the Foo template class and declaring but not defining a ctor only for a given value of the NTTP N,
// foo.hpp
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
struct Foo {
    template<int M = N, std::enable_if_t<M == 2, int> = 0>
    Foo(int);
};


the cpp file defining that ctor and explicitly instantiating Foo for a value that corresponds to the ctor not being SFINAEd out,
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

template<int N>
template<int M, std::enable_if_t<M == 2, int>>
Foo<N>::Foo(int) {}

template struct Foo<2>;


the main TU, that instantiates an object of Foo<2> class,
// main.hpp
#include "foo.hpp"

int main() {
    Foo<2>{0};
}



If I try to compile the two TUs above and link them, I get the following error from the linker:
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Foo<2>::Foo<2, 0>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Indeed, I don't see any symbols from foo.cpp, as this
nm foo.o

gives no output.

If I add another, un-constrained ctor, e.g.
// foo.hpp
// …
struct Foo {
    Foo(int, int);
// …

and
// foo.cpp
// …
template<int N>
Foo<N>::Foo(int, int) {}
// …

then I do get what I expect:
nm foo.o | c++filt
0000000000000000 W Foo<2>::Foo(int, int)
0000000000000000 W Foo<2>::Foo(int, int)
0000000000000000 n Foo<2>::Foo(int, int)


Main problem is that you constructor template parameter is not deducible, so what Foo<2>{0} does it mean? Which constructor template should be selected (ignoring SFINAE), how it this sytax actuall Foo<2>::Foo<2, 0>(int) is selected? You need constructor argument which will consume constructor template parameter, so it can be deduced.

Here I've made your example compiling and linking, but this seems like gcc bug (IMO should not compile at all).

@MarekR, but the declaration of the constructor has int M = N, so why would M need to be deduced? After all, if I move the definition in the header and only leave #include "foo.hpp" and template struct Foo<2>; in the cpp, the linking works.

Why do you even have M at all, considering that it is not possible to specify any value for M other than N? Normally, we have enable_if constraints to prevent some instantiations, but in this case, all the instantiations it prevents are ones that you cannot even request in the first place.

@BrianBi, I'm not sure I follow, but N is a template parameter of the class so how can I disable the ctor for just one value of N without templating the ctor itself in order to use SFINAE? Yes, M is always == N, but it is a template parameter of the ctor, not of the class, so I can use it to SFINAE-out the ctor.

Oh, I just saw that this is C++17, I get it now, you can't use requires.

Explicitly instantiate template class doesn't instantiate template member function.
You need to explicitly instantiate those methods too:
// template Foo<2>::Foo<2, 0>(int); // Not supported by clang
template Foo<2>::Foo(int);

Demo
Demo

This is something I attempted, but didn't even try to compile it as Clang's red squiggles put me off. But yeah, I see it works for GCC! Unfortunately, I need code that compiles on Clang, GCC, MSVC, so the question becomes: is Clang correct to reject this code?

Clang is ok with template Foo<2>::Foo(int);
